# How to pass template function with default arguments to std::call_once

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, c++14

I need to use std::call_once in my templatized singleton class but currently below sample code is not compiling :

```
std::once_flag flag;
class LifeTrackerHelper
{
public:
template<class T>
inline static int SetLongevity(std::unique_ptr<T>& pobj,unsigned int longevity = 0)
{
    return 0;
}
};
template<class T>
class Singleton
{
   public:    
   inline static T* getInstance()
   {
     static std::unique_ptr<T> ptr(new T());  
     std::call_once(flag,&LifeTrackerHelper::SetLongevity<T>,ptr);  
     //static int i = LifeTrackerHelper::SetLongevity<T>(ptr);
     // if call_once is commented and above line uncommented this will work
     return ptr.get();
   }
};
class Test
{
    public:
    void fun()
    {
        std::cout<<"Having fun...."<<std::endl;
    }
};
int main()
{

  Singleton<Test>::getInstance()->fun(); 
}
```

So need help in understanding how to properly use std::call_once here.

Comment: Why -1, Is anything wrong with question ??

Comment: Where is the declaration of `flag`? And what exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: thanks i added flag to sample, i am just trying to modify generic singleton created by my colleague

Comment: The problem is the `ptr` passed to `call_once`. I assume `call_once` will try to invoke the copy constructor for `std::unique_ptr` and this will result in an error because copy constructor of `std::unique_ptr` is deleted. I haven't tested though.

Comment: I tried using std::ref on unique_ptr but that also is not working

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is `&LifeTrackerHelper::SetLongevity<T>` is a function pointer expecting a `unique_ptr` and an `unsigned int`, but it only gets the one argument. While the actual function has a default value for the second argument, it needs both arguments when called by a function pointer.

You can fix it by passing another argument:

```
std::call_once(flag, &LifeTrackerHelper::SetLongevity<T>, ptr, 0);
```

Or you can wrap it in a lambda:

```
std::call_once(flag, [](std::unique_ptr<T>& p){ return LifeTrackerHelper::SetLongevity<T>(p); }, ptr);
```

---

According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once), before C++17 the arguments to `call_once` will be copied or moved. So far, I haven't gotten any errors passing a `unique_ptr`, but it might be wise to use `std::ref` on it.

Comment: But why we need to pass even default arguments when using function pointer

Comment: When using c++11 i need to use std::ref otherwise getting compilation error http://cpp.sh/3p3mv