# How to use overloaded function with std::call_once

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, c++14

In addition to this question [How to pass template function with default arguments to std::call_once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44015883/how-to-pass-template-function-to-stdcall-once?noredirect=1#comment75059924_44015883) that was resolved by passing even default arguments when using function pointers but now when i tried this solution in real code i found that it is not working because there is one overloaded function also :

```
std::once_flag flag;
class LifeTrackerHelper
{
public:
template<class T>
inline static int SetLongevity(std::unique_ptr<T>& pobj,unsigned int longevity = 0)
{
    return 0;
}
template<class T>
inline static int SetLongevity(unsigned int longevity = 0)
{
    return 0;
}

};
template<class T>
class Singleton
{
   public:    
   inline static T* getInstance()
   {
     static std::unique_ptr<T> ptr(new T());  
     std::call_once(flag,&LifeTrackerHelper::SetLongevity<T>,std::ref(ptr),0);  
     //static int i = LifeTrackerHelper::SetLongevity<T>(ptr);
     // if call_once is commented and above line uncommented this will work
     return ptr.get();
   }
};
class Test
{
    public:
    void fun()
    {
        std::cout<<"Having fun...."<<std::endl;
    }
};
;
int main()
{
  Singleton<Test>::getInstance()->fun(); 
  return 0;
}
```

So there are any special rules when working with overloaded functions in std::call_once

Comment: Why don't you simply employ the use of a lambda as your `std::call_once` parameter?

Comment: `std::call_once(flag,[&ptr]{LifeTrackerHelper::SetLongevity(ptr, 0);}); `

Answer (score 2):

You can use `static_cast<>()` to specify which overload you mean. For example,

```
 std::call_once(flag,
         static_cast<int (*)(std::unique_ptr<T>&, unsigned int)>(
                 &LifeTrackerHelper::SetLongevity<T>),
         std::ref(ptr), 0);
```

You can also use a temporary variable for the same effect.

```
int (*initfn)(std::unique_ptr<T>&, unsigned int) =
        &LifeTrackerHelper::SetLongevity<T>;
std::call_once(flag, initfn, std::ref(ptr), 0);
```

Comment: This looks quite unpleasant there is no better approach

Comment: Yes as of now i m using that approach only but just want to know if something better can be done with function pointers only